# Web Frameworks versus Web Servers?

Tags: django, node.js, apache, http, web

What are the differences between technologies like `Flask`, `Django`, `NodeJS`, and `Apache`? With `Apache` and `NodeJS`, they can function as a web server, interfacing your server-side code with HTTP requests. Do `Flask` and `Django` also provide this capability or do they provide different functionality?

Comment: yes, they are both server side web frameworks.  Django can work with Apache and other webservers.  I'm not sure about Flask

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apache/nginx are web servers, they can serve both static content(html,jpg, etc), and dynamic content generated by web apps.

Django/Flask/Express on NodeJS are web frameworks, they provide the common functionality for writing a web application, like request routing/ORM/session/template. It makes writing a web app much easier - you only need to 'fill in the blanks'.

Most of the time, a web app (implemented in a web framework) sits behind a web server, and process requests handed over by the web server. But sometimes, the framework itself can function as a web server, like Tornado/Express.

NodeJS is neither a web framework or a web server. You can think of it as a Javascript cross-platform runtime environment.